# Why isn't Google Webmaster Tools reporting this backlink?

Tags: google, google-search-console, html, backlinks

Index page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Links</title>
        <meta name="robots" CONTENT="index, follow" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=wrap>
            <div id=head>
                <div class=head-text>Links</div>
            </div>
                <div id=context-bg>
                    <p /><a href="http://www.url.com"><b>Anchor text</b></a>

                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

This page is indexed in Google (checked with Google WebmasterTools), but whenever i link to a website it doesnt show up for the linked back as backlink.
**The page is now 1/2 months indexed in Google**
Why is that, what im doing wrong ?

Comment: Is this code on the website you are linking to?

Comment: No, it's from website A to website B. else it will be not seen as a backlink. -_-'

Comment: Do you control both websites?

Comment: yes i do controle them both

Comment: Where are seeing that the link is not being reported as a backlink?

Comment: GoogleWebmasterTools, you can check backlinks to the website

Comment: Backlinks depend on the client properly reporting the referrer. Try using a different browser to make sure that's not the issue. Log the request headers server-side to make sure they're actually being received. Then report back.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [Google's help document about the links to your site report in Google Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/55281?hl=en).  It states:

> Not all links to your site may be listed. This is normal.

This tool is not meant to be a full report of all the links to your site that Google can find.  Rather Google intends it to be a representative sample of the links to your site so that you can see how many other sites are linking to you.

Many webmasters would like to have a more complete list.   I've especially seen Webmasters complain when they are trying to disavow bad links to their site and cannot get a complete list of the bad URLs using this tool.

Just because a specific URL is not showing up, it shouldn't be considered a bad sign.   Google knows about many more links than it reports.   The reported links don't appear to be more or less likely to be counted as good references to your site by the Google ranking algorithms compared to links that don't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try submitting the page containing the backlink to [Ping Farm](http://www.pingfarm.com/), sometimes, it does accelerate the detection process.